# How to display confirm box on website in php

Tags: javascript, php, session, alert, confirm

i want to display an confirm box with two button yes and no, when user press yes than index page will be displayed and when user press no this redirect to another page. this confirm msgbox display only once when first time website open not on every reloading of page. Thanks

Comment: check this maybe help you http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_confirm2

Comment: Try [PHP Cookies](http://php.net/manual/en/features.cookies.php)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code

```
 <script>
 var confirm = confirm("sample message?");
 if(confirm) {
     // index page
     window.location.url = ""; // your url index page
  } else {
     // other page
     window.location.url = ""; // your url other page
  }
 </script>
```

Comment: i already try that but if i execute it on onLoad event then it execute on every reloading of page, and i can't set php session variable through javascript(so i can't test this on next reloading of page)

Comment: yes it will display again and again because you put it on onload event

Comment: so how can i fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do all stuff in javascript.
Javascript Function you can use.
Also you need to set cookie at browser and check if cookie is set.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x;
    if (confirm("Press a button!") == true) {
        x = "You pressed OK!";
    } else {
        x = "You pressed Cancel!";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
    var txt;
    var r = confirm("Press a button!");
    if (r == true) {
        txt = "You pressed OK!";
    } else {
        txt = "You pressed Cancel!";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Are you sure?</title>
 
 <script>
     function areYouSure() {
            var res = confirm("Are you sure?");
            return res; //true or false
        }
 </script>
 
</head>
<body>
                    
<form method="POST" action="action_page.php">
<!--
...
-->
<input type="submit" onclick="return areYouSure()"/>

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi AA, great your taking time to answer, what would really help though is some description why you reccomend this and what it does, remembering people of all skill levels and experience might be looking here for answers later :) https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering